# How to make a rectangular div shift down when it larger than its parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to map objects of cars in react js to display the names of vehicles in a rectangular box, but the box surpasses the parent container. I want the box to automatically increase the height of the parent container when it reaches the end of the parent container. Please check out the images for visualization.

Thanks.

[image: Visualization of what I am trying to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <button>Button 3</button>
      <button>Button 4</button>
      <button>Button 5</button>
      <button>Button 6</button>
      <button>Button 7</button>
      <button>Button 8</button>
</div>
```

Comment: are you aware that your CSS make no sense? Not sure why you got an upvote

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for that. I didn't realize the syntax issue. I just quickly created the example using one of the online editors and it didn't complain and worked as expected. :)